# I can't write anything on NTFS drives in kubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, kubuntu, write-protect, ntfs-3g

I use kubuntu 16.10 on a dual boot with windows 10. problem is I can't write/modify any data on other partitions when i use kubuntu. I can only write to my kubuntu partition. all other partitions are formatted with ntfs.
what should I do? I already have ntfs-3g in latest version

Answer (score 6):

You need to disable fast startup in Windows so that the system is cleanly unmounted on shutdown. This will allow you to dual-boot safely.

You need to do this because Windows normally does not shutdown any more, instead it logs off the current user and hibernates the system core. What this means is that the drive is not safe to be modified by other operating systems such as Linux until it is **properly** shut down.

Linux, thankfully, is detecting this state and mounting the drive read-only. If it had not done this then it could modify the Windows partition in a way that is unexpected by the (currently hibernated) Windows system which could cause instability, crashing or data loss.

Doing the steps below should disable the hibernation and make the filesystem safe for dual booting, at the cost of slowing down your Windows boot times.

Go to Power Options in the control panel (search for "power" in cortana)

[image]

Select "Choose what the power buttons do"

[image]

And then click "change settings that are currently unavailable and then uncheck the "Turn on fast start-up" option.

[image]

Comment: If i do that, is that means that I can't use hibenation on windows anymore?

Comment: You should be able to hibernate your system in the normal method of Start -> Turn Off -> Hibernate, but if you have the ability to boot to Linux before Windows is resumed then you won't then be able to access the Windows partition from Linux. You should *never* try to access a different OS while one system is hibernated on your computer. Data corruption can and, sooner or later, will occur.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to turn off fast start-up, you can just restart the system whenever you want to use linux. This should completely shut down windows

Comment: If you do use hibernate or sleep you should always boot into that system first and shut it down properly before using the other system. This doesn't mean you can't use those features, you just need to be aware of what you can and cannot do.

Comment: @Blaine that is a possibility, but has the downside that if you shutdown the night before and boot your machine in the morning and go straight into Linux then you have to reboot back into Windows just to reboot again to make the drive accessible in Linux. Could be a bit aggravating.

Comment: I understand. i only use hibernate if only i just need to go back to windows. Problem is, I tried completely shutting off windows and launching kubuntu. But the problem remains same. No matter I restart, shut down or hibernate

Comment: @VishwaMadushan what do you get if you do `sudo mount -o remount,rw /path/to/NTFSPartition` ? (Fix the path as necessary)