# Compatibility of Linux OS with Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, multi-boot, compatibility, bootrepair

I have a Windows 8.1 64-bit i3 processor system. I have two questions to ask.

Firstly, I want to ask that which Linux operating system is best compatible with my current OS? Previously, I dual booted Ubuntu 14.04.5 alongside Windows 8.1 and it didn't go well. I was facing mounting issues and wifi problem on my system. I heard that this Ubuntu version is not much compatible with Windows 8 and later version. Is this true?

Secondly, I uninstalled the Ubuntu from my system but didn't do boot repair. So now whenever I start my system, I get a grub window leading me to choices of OS. So is this okay if I again dual boot a linux OS without boot repairing (as I am facing some issues with boot repairing)?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? I.e. is your boot disk MBR or GPT partitioned?

Comment: UEFI , and I booted using a flash drive.

Comment: The problems mounting drives can be alleviated by turning off Windows fast boot: http://superuser.com/questions/1166344/i-cant-write-anything-on-ntfs-drives-in-kubuntu-16-10/1166351#1166351 This has the downside of making Windows boot slightly slower though.

Answer (score 2):

By comparing the hardware compatibility and community aspects, Ubuntu might be the answer for your first question. Try and LTS(Long Term Support) version instead of the newest one around. The mount issues you're facing on Linux may be due to the fast boot feature on Windows [Read Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting)...
You could disable the fast startup to get rid of mount issues on dual boot. [Disabling Hybrid Boot In Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/656459/disabling-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8)

And its absolutely okay to dual boot install another Linux operating system as the installation contains(mostly it does) a grub bootloader install which installs or reinstalls the grub for you.